# Рефлексия. Пространство имен интерфейса

Tags: c#, .net, рефлексия

Допустим у меня есть список интерфейсов моей `dll`

Список интерфейсов я беру таким способом :

```
        var dll = Assembly.LoadFile("outerlib.dll");

        var interfaces = asm.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsInterface);
```

И мне необходимо по каждому интерфейсу взять объявленные у него пространства имен.

Допустим у нас есть только один интерфейс :

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Outerlib.Controllers
{
    public interface IRightManagerController
    {
        Task<IHttpActionResult> GetRoles();

        Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUserRole(string userName);
    }
}
```

На выходе хотелось бы иметь список из следующих элементов

```
System.Threading.Tasks;
System.Web.Http;
```

Comment: Зачем? А если бы было так: `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult> GetRoles();`?

Comment: @Igor кодогенерация - кустарная. ну и предполагается что так не будут писать

Comment: На уровне `IL` ваших `using` не существует. Так что никак

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странная у вас задача, но можно сделать вот так:

```
static void ProcessType(Type type, HashSet<string> namespaces)
{
    namespaces.Add(type.Namespace);
    if (type.IsGenericType)
    {
        foreach (var genericArgument in type.GetGenericArguments())
            ProcessType(genericArgument, namespaces);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var asm = Assembly.LoadFile("outerlib.dll");
    var interfaces = asm.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsInterface);
    var namespaces = new HashSet<string>();
    foreach (var @interface in interfaces)
    {
        var methods = @interface.GetMethods();
        foreach (var method in methods)
        {
            ProcessType(method.ReturnType, namespaces);
            foreach (var parameter in method.GetParameters())
                ProcessType(parameter.ParameterType, namespaces);
        }
        // если нужно, можно добавить аналогичный код для Properties
    }

    foreach (var @namespace in namespaces.OrderBy(n => n))
        Console.WriteLine(@namespace);
}
```